Teams Toolkit App Fails to Install with "Something went wrong"
I have been using Teams Toolkit to build an app. Everything was working just fine before debugging and starting the app through Visual Studio using the browser. Then today, without any changes it is failing to install the app.
The popup window that normally allows the user to accept and add the app opens but quickly changes to a dialog with "Something went wrong".
When I see nothing in the console logs that doesn't appear when opening Teams in a browser without attempting to launch from debug.
What I do find when I inspect the network traffic is two failed calls by the Teams app that seem to be related to pulling the manifest and validating it.
First is a call to: https://teams.microsoft.com/api/appstudio/appdefinitions/$%7B%7BTEAMS_APP_ID%7D%7D/manifest
which fails with a 500 error
The second is a call to:
https://teams.microsoft.com/api/apps/part/amer-01/beta/users/apps/definitions/appPackage/validate
which fails with a 400 error
This is a basic personal tab app with no bots or other complexities and I have found no solutions online that fit this specific problem. The app manifest was also validated through the Teams dev portal and reported no issues.
All of this appears to have nothing to do with our app itself, only between the Teams client app and Teams APIs online.
